# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(1-x)^2}{1+x+x^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to evaluate this integral.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(1-x)^2}{1+x+x^2}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\ln x}$$

$1+x+x^2=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+1-\frac{1}{4}=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{3}{4}$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(1-x)^2}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\ln x}$$

$$-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2y}(1-e^y)^2}{(e^y+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}}\frac{\mathrm dy}{y}$$

I did a useless substitution, I was hoping to get a simpler integral.

Comment: It is $$\log \left(\frac{3 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3}{8
   \pi ^2}\right)$$

Comment: WolframAlpha gives $\log(18)-3\log\Gamma(1/3)$.

Comment: This reminds me of [Malmsten's integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Johan_Malmsten).

Comment: @dxdydz do you have any references on the evaluation of Malmstein's integrals?

Comment: @clathratus [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257381156_Rediscovery_of_Malmsten's_integrals_their_evaluation_by_contour_integration_methods_and_some_related_results) and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.08435.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function

$$ I(s) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{s+1} (1 - x)^2}{1+x+x^2}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log x}. $$

Then

\begin{align*}
I'(s)
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{s+1} (1 - x)^3}{1-x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{u^{(s-1)/3} (1 - u^{1/3})^3}{1-u}\,\mathrm{d}u \tag{$x=u^{1/3}$} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=0}^{3} \binom{3}{k} (-1)^{k-1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-u^{(s+k-1)/3}}{1-u}\,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=0}^{3} \binom{3}{k} (-1)^{k-1} \psi((s+k+2)/3),
\end{align*}

where we utilized the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{3}\binom{3}{k}(-1)^k = 0$. Also, $\psi$ is the digamma function and we utilized the identity that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-u^z}{1-u} \, \mathrm{d}z = \gamma + \psi(z+1)$ in the final step. Together with $I(\infty) = 0$, we get

\begin{align*}
I(0)
&= -\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{0}^{R} I'(s) \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{3} \binom{3}{k} (-1)^{k} \left[ \log\Gamma((R+k+2)/3) - \log\Gamma((k+2)/3) \right] \\
&= - \sum_{k=0}^{3} \binom{3}{k} (-1)^{k} \log\Gamma((k+2)/3) \\
&= \log(18) - 3\log\Gamma(1/3).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x\pars{1 - x}^{2} \over 1 + x + x^{2}}\,{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}}} =
\int_{0}^{1}{x - 2x^{2} + x^{3} \over 1 - x^{3}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}x^{t}\,\dd t}^{\ds{-\,{1 - x \over \ln\pars{x}}}}\ \,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{1 + t} - 2x^{2 + t} + x^{3 + t} \over 1 - x^{3}}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x^{3}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,&
-\,{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{-1/3 + t/3} - 2x^{t/3} + x^{1/3 + t/3} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t/3 - 1/3} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
2\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t/3} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t/3 + 1/3} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}\dd t
\end{align}

> With [Identity $\mathbf{\color{black}{6.3.22}}$ in A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) :

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x\pars{1 - x}^{2} \over 1 + x + x^{2}}\,{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{{t \over 3} + {2 \over 3}} - 2\Psi\pars{{t \over 3} + 1} + \Psi\pars{{t \over 3} + {4 \over 3}}}\dd t
\end{align}

> $\ds{\Psi}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x\pars{1 - x}^{2} \over 1 + x + x^{2}}\,{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{{t \over 3} + {2 \over 3}}} -
2\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{{t \over 3} + 1}} +
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{{t \over 3} + {4 \over 3}}}
\,\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ 1}
\\[8mm] = &\
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1}} -
2\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{4 \over 3}} + \ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{5 \over 3}} -\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2 \over 3}}
\\[2mm] &\
+ 2\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1}} - \ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{4 \over 3}}
\\[8mm] = &\
-3\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{4 \over 3}} +
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{5 \over 3}} -
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2 \over 3}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Gamma}$ is the
[Gamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm).

---

With
[$\ds{\Gamma}$ Recurrence Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm)
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{-3\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{4 \over 3}}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\overbrace{-3\ln\pars{1 \over 3}}^{\ds{\ln\pars{27}}}\ -\ 3\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1 \over 3}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{5 \over 3}}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\phantom{-3\,}\ln\pars{2 \over 3} + \ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2 \over 3}}}
\end{array}\right.
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

---

\eqref{1} and \eqref{2} $\ds{\implies}$
$$
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{x\pars{1 - x}^{2} \over 1 + x + x^{2}}\,{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}}} =
\bbx{\ln\pars{18 \over \Gamma^{3}\pars{1/3}}} \approx
-0.0659
$$